# Python ElementTree XPath multiple conditions for attributes

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I'm trying to select nodes from my XML by the following rules:

***parent of node named "tag" with attributes k='k1' and (v='v1' or v='v2')***

How can I achieve it using python and ElementTree? I tried the following code, but got an error "SyntaxError: invalid predicate"

```
roads = root.findall(".//tag[@k='k1'][@v='v1' or @v='v2']/..")
roads = root.findall(".//tag[@k='k1' and (@v='v1' or @v='v2')]/..")
```

**UPDATE**

XML sample

```
<parent>
  <tag k="k1" v="v1"/>
  <tag k="k1" v="v2"/>
  <tag k="k1" v="v3"/>
 </parent>
```

Comment: First, can you edit your question with a short, representative sample of your xml? Second, can you use a library like lxml or is ET required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ET xpath support is very limited. But this hack should work

```
roads = root.findall(".//tag[@k='k1']/..") or root.findall(".//tag[@k='k2']/..")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this, but it seems like XPath isn't the way to go about filtering for the right attributes.

`roads = [el for el in root.findall(".//tag") if el.attrib["k"] == "k1" and el.attrib["v"] in ("v1", "v2")]`

If it makes it clearer, the logic can be rewritten as `el.attrib["k"] == "k1" and (el.attrib["v"] == "v1" or el.attrib["v"] == "v2")`.